# How to set a Fragment tag by code?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

I haven't found something like `setTag(String tagName)` method in the `Fragment` class. The only way to set a `Fragment` tag that I have found is by doing a `FragmentTransaction` and passing a tag name as parameter.

Is this the only way to explicitly set a `Fragment` tag by code?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Yes. So the only way is at transaction time, e.g. using `add`, `replace`, or as part of the layout.

I determined this through an examination of the compatibility sources as I briefly looked for similar at some point in the past.

Comment: Your answer lies [here][1]
in the post on stackoverflow

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363072/android-set-fragment-id

Comment: Use FragmentTransaction's add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag) as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13244471/4002895

@PJL Please edit your answer.This answer misleading people

Comment: That's pretty inconvenient.

Answer (score 79):

You can set tag to fragment in this way:

```
Fragment fragmentA = new FragmentA();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.MainFrameLayout,fragmentA,"YOUR_TARGET_FRAGMENT_TAG")
    .addToBackStack("YOUR_SOURCE_FRAGMENT_TAG").commit();
```

Comment: Where i use this code? In getItem in FragmentPagerAdapter?

Answer (score 38):

You can provide a tag inside your activity layout xml file.

Supply the `android:tag attribute` with a unique string.

Just as you would assign an id in a layout xml.

```
    android:tag="unique_tag"
```

[link to developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding)

Comment: That would work if one was using a layout file.  But this question refers to setting the tag dynamically in Java.

Comment: this was the answer I needed because sometimes while using some libraries, you don't have control over fragment transactions so you can't programmatically set the tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way I have found :

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
          // Let's first dynamically add a fragment into a frame container
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(). 
              replace(R.id.flContainer, new DemoFragment(), "SOMETAG").
              commit();
          // Now later we can lookup the fragment by tag
          DemoFragment fragmentDemo = (DemoFragment) 
              getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("SOMETAG");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also get all fragments like this:

**For v4 fragmets**

```
List<Fragment> allFragments = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
```

**For app.fragment**

```
List<Fragment> allFragments = getFragmentManager().getFragments();
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there's a simpler way to achieve this if you are using a `DialogFragment` (not a `Fragment`):

```
val yourDialogFragment = YourDialogFragment()
yourDialogFragment.show(
    activity.supportFragmentManager,
    "YOUR_TAG_FRAGMENT"
)
```

Under the hood, the `show()` method does create a `FragmentTransaction` and adds the tag by using the `add()` method. But it's much more convenient to use the `show()` method in my opinion.

You could shorten it for `Fragment` too, by using a [Kotlin Extension](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html) :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been 6 years ago but if anyone is facing the same problem do like I've done:

Create a custom `Fragment` Class with a tag field:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
 private String _myTag;
 public void setMyTag(String value)
 {
   if("".equals(value))
     return;
   _myTag = value;
 }
 //other code goes here
}
```

Before adding the fragment to the `sectionPagerAdapter` set the tag just like that:

```
 MyFragment mfrag= new MyFragment();
 mfrag.setMyTag("TAG_GOES_HERE");
 sectionPagerAdapter.AddFragment(mfrag);
```

Comment: The question wasn't about setting a property on a Fragment. [It was about being able to retrieve an existing Fragment instance without keeping a reference around](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String)).

Comment: @Th3Wolf, Thanks. Your answer solved my problem....

Answer (score -24):

You can add the tag as a property for the `Fragment` arguments. It will be automatically restored if the fragment is destroyed and then recreated by the **OS**.

***Example***:-

```
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("TAG", "my tag");
    fragment.setArguments(args);
```

Comment: I got what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: What did you get?! That's not how you set a tag for Fragment not by a long shot

Comment: This isn't how you set tag.