# Android - Set fragment id

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I set a `Fragment`'s `Id` so that I can use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.--)`?

Comment: You can set it in layout xml file

Answer (score 120):

**You can't set a fragment's ID programmatically**.

There is however, a `String tag` that you can set inside the FragmentTransaction which can be used to uniquely identify a Fragment.

As Aleksey pointed out, you can pass an ID to `FragmentTransaction`'s `add(int, Fragment)` method. However, **this does not specify the ID for a Fragment.** It specifies the ID of a `ViewGroup` to insert the `Fragment` into. This is not that useful for the purpose I expect you have, because it does not uniquely identify `Fragment`s, but `ViewGroup`s. These IDs are of *containers* that one *or more* fragments can be added to dynamically. Using such a method to identify `Fragment`s would require you to add `ViewGroup`s dynamically to the Layout for every `Fragment` you insert. That would be pretty cumbersome.

So if your question is how to create a unique identifier for a Fragment you're adding dynamically, the answer is to use `FragmentTransaction`'s [add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29)  method and `FragmentManager`'s [findFragmentByTag(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29) method.

In one of my apps, I was forced to generate strings dynamically. But it's not that expensive relative to the actual FragmentTransaction, anyway.

Another advantage to the tag method is that it can identify a Fragment that isn't being added to the UI. See FragmentTransaction's [add(Fragment, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) method. `Fragment`s need not have `View`s! They can also be used to persist ephemeral state between config changes!

Comment: If I use the tag and not the ID for the fragment, how would I use the replace call which needs a fragment resource id?

Comment: @TomDignan how about a fragment that will be added in a ViewPager? How can I set his tag? I can't use transactions in this situation.

Comment: @GuilhE Activity provides an addFragment() method which you can reference from the viewpager. Keeping the tag before that could be accomplished with a hashmap.

Comment: Can the answer be edited a tiny bit to emphasize that you can set id in xml layout? Because I personally did not read other questions and was under impression that there is no way at all to set id to the fragment...

Answer (score 45):

Turns out you may not need to know the fragment id.

From the docs:

```
public abstract Fragment findFragmentById (int id)

Finds a fragment that was identified by the given id either
when inflated from XML or as the container ID when added in
a transaction.
```

The important part is "as the container ID when added in a transaction".

so:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragment_holder, new AwesomeFragment())
    .commit();
```

and then

```
AwesomeFragment awesome = (AwesomeFragment)
     getSupportFragmentManager()
          .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_holder);
```

will get you whatever (awesome) fragment is held in R.id.fragment_holder.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases you can use the fragment tag as well as the ID.
You can set the tag value in `FragmentTransaction.add(Fragment fragment, String tag );`.
Then you can use the command `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String tab)` to find the fragment in question.

Answer (score 2):

As Tom and others already mention, there are ways to put a tag on a fragment and use that tag for identification. A subsequent problem I've come across with those solutions is that the fragment doesn't get a tag until it's associated with the Activity (or, actually, the `FragmentManager`). What to do if one needs to identify a fragment before it has been tagged?

My solutions so far all rely on the oldest (Java) trick in the world: create a minimalistic template fragment which takes an id in one of it's constructors and provides a `getFragmentId()` method which returns that id. I then let those fragments that need early identification extend that template and; voila! Problem solved.

This solution might, unfortunately, require a set of template fragments, one for each fragment type, `ListFragment`, `DialogFragment` or plain old `Fragment` (POFO?!) that need early identification. But this is manageable in the case of fragments I think, considering the gains provided.

Sorry for tearing up healing wounds :-)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

To add a fragment:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentToBeAdded, tag).commit();
```

To identify existing fragment:

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentName);
```

Comment: Answer is not relevant to question. Please update the answer.
Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

When using a tag please do make sure to add the

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

method so that your Fragment is resumed instead of destroyed as mentioned in the developer guides.

> If you don't call addToBackStack() when you perform a transaction that removes a fragment, then that fragment is destroyed when the transaction is committed and the user cannot navigate back to it. Whereas, if you do call addToBackStack() when removing a fragment, then the fragment is stopped and is later resumed if the user navigates back.

You can find this at the end [of this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#Transactions).

I lost about 30 minutes trying to figure out why my Fragment was not being found through a simple `findFragmentByTag();` call

Answer (score -2):

In addition to Tom's answer, replace method also supports the fragment tag, in addition to add  method.