# Textview is null on first click but updates on second click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, textview

It's small Android 2.2 test application using the Compatibility Package. I am trying to update the textview on another fragment on another activity on list item selection. But problem is that everytime the first click returns nullpointer exception and only on the second try its text is changing. I would like to know why is the happening and what is a good solution.

**ListActivity:-**

```
public class ListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // Check to see if there is a frame in which to embed the
        // detail fragment directly in the containing UI.
        View detailsFrame = findViewById(R.id.detailcontainer);
        if (detailsFrame != null
                && detailsFrame.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

            DetailFragment detailFragment = (DetailFragment)    getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.detailcontainer);

            if (detailFragment == null) {

                detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
            }

            // Execute a transaction, replacing any existing fragment
            // with this one inside the frame.

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.detailcontainer, detailFragment).commit();

            detailFragment.setTextView(index);

        } else {

            // Otherwise we need to launch a new activity to display
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("index", index);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

**ListFragment :-**

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

    private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        String[] countries = new String[] { "India", "Pakistan", "Sri Lanka",
                "China", "Bangladesh", "Nepal", "Afghanistan", "North Korea",
                "South Korea", "Japan" };

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        // Populate list
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                countries);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // operation to do when an item is clicked
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ListItem Number " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                listener.onItemSelected(position);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(int index);
    }

    // To ensure that the host activity implements this interface
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (activity instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
            listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
        } else {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implemenet ListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    public void operation(int index) {

        listener.onItemSelected(index);
    }

}
```

**Detail Activity :-**

```
public class DetailActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DetailFragment details;
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

            finish();
            return;
        }

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
            details = new DetailFragment();
            details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();
        }

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int index = extras.getInt("index");
        try {
            details = (DetailFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.detailfragment);
            details.setTextView(index);

        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**DetailFragment :-**

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    String[] capitals;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (container == null)
            return null;

        capitals = new String[] { "delhi", "karachi", "colombo", "beijing",
                "dhaka", "katmandu", "Afghanistan", "pyongyang", "seoul",
                "tokyo" };

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    public void setTextView(int index) {

        try {
            TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailView);
            view.setText(capitals[index]);

        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            ex.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getShownIndex() {
        return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
    }
}
```

Update:- I am adding the detailFragment xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/lightblue"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detailView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/detail_frag" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It givs nullpointerException at :- TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailView);

Comment: what will be index value

Comment: index value is coming correct. depending on the item selected.

Comment: show  me that xml (detailView) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated2**

Just initialize your `TextView` in `onCreateView()` no need to create `DetailFragment` with parametrize just put in comment

Check the **details** object whether its null or not if null initialize as you do and then called `setTextView()`

```
if(details==null)
    details = new DetailFragment(index);
else
   setTextView(index);
```

TextView inside `onCreateView()` and used their

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    String[] capitals;

    int index;
    private TextView textView;

    public DetailFragment(int index){
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (container == null)
            return null;

        capitals = new String[] { "delhi", "karachi", "colombo", "beijing",
                "dhaka", "katmandu", "Afghanistan", "pyongyang", "seoul",
                "tokyo" };

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_fragment, container, false);
        // Initialize textView
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.detailView);
        setTextView(index); // set value value here for first time
        return v;
    }

    public void setTextView(int index) {
        if(textView!=null)
            textView.setText(capitals[index]); 
    }

    public int getShownIndex() {
        return getArguments().getInt("index", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get a warning - This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)

Comment: Also it changes for the first click but when i select another item, it doesn't change because settext is happening only at createView.

Comment: can u please tell me how can i change the textview every time i select a different item?

Comment: Again I come back to the same problem. The textView is null for the first click and so text is not updated. Only starts working from the second click

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing details.setTextView(index) in DetailActivity  , set the value of TextView in the DetailFragment's onActivityCreated while passing the value to be set in fragments setArgument method in the Detailactivity...

```
  DetailsFragment details = new DetailsFragment();
  details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());  // pass the value of text view here
```

And In fragment onActivityCreated get that value via getArguments() and set it in textview..

**EDIT for sending value Selected to loaded Fragment**

In List Activity

```
  detailFragment = getFragmentbyTag
  if(detailFragment == null)
      Create Fragment and Add it and Set Arguments here as well
  else
      detailFragment.setTextView(value); // fragment already loaded no need to set arguments
```

if you want to replace each time and not add once and use the added/loaded fragment , use setarguments each time.... and remove previous fragment and add new fragment( with Arguments) But added once and reused is preferred instead of removing and adding/ replacing on each click

Comment: thanks. that does solve the partial error but i wanted to replace my container with fragment on item click in the landscape mode. How will I be able to send the index to the fragment and update the text depending upon which item is clicked.

Comment: Once the fragment is loaded and in Landscape mode you check in ListActivity you check   if detailFragment ==null create new fragment else get the fragment already loaded via its TAG ( you can Set TAG to a fragment when adding it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363072/android-set-fragment-id ) after retrieving already loaded fragment update its text via setTextView method.. meaning dont replace the fragment each time , only add once and use it throughout and set new text to the TextView in it , hope i am able to convey my point

Answer (score 0):

did you tried using this

```
TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detailView);
```

instead of this

```
 TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailView);
```

Comment: I can't do that. Its in Fragment. I need the view.

Comment: oh ok, i dint see it is in Fragment, Sorry!!