# Assigning ID to dynamically created ListFragment

Tags: android, bundle, fragment

I am currently working on this code for Android and it has a dynamically created listfragment. Even the listview is assigned to it dynamically. It takes a simple cursor object from SQL Lite and assigns it to an adapter.

It all works great, problem is when orientation changes happen, the savedInstanceState bundle is always null. Even if I override OnSaveInstanceState and add items to that bundle or onCreateView. I did some research and found out that this is happening because the fragment has no ID assigned to it.

I am having a little bit of a problem as to where to assign an ID to to the listfragment and how. I am using FragmentTransaction and using a TAG identifier.

I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this question: [Android - Set fragment id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363072/android-set-fragment-id)

You can't assign an ID to a dynamically created fragment.

You can, however, create an .xml layout file and assign an id to your fragment there with `android:id="@+id/my_fragment"`. Is there a reason you are not using an xml-defined fragment?

Comment: I was looking at this question earlier, I just read it again a little more in depth and I am sad to find out that you can't assign ID to a dynamically created fragment (Which makes no sense -1 for android dev team). I started coding my entire app with dynamically created fragments because its really good practice and really good code re-usability. Doesn't matter though its not an impossible task I can just used sharedpreferences with object serialization to get the task completed. I was just trying to figure out if I could avoid that approach.

Comment: When I just started exploring Android I also tried to write my apps with dynamically created layouts, but I later realized that it was actually easier to do it via xml layout files. Code re-usability doesn't suffer and it lets you keep the UI and the algorithms separate. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: A lesson I refuse to learn lol but for my app I am using sherlockActionBar along with toggle switches for replacing multiple fragments dynamically within each tab, so I can't use xml layouts for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this while you do the transaction. If you call

```
FragmentTransaction.replace(containerViewId, fragment, tag);
```

**OR**

```
FragmentTransaction.add(fragment,tag)
```

**OR**

```
FragmentTransaction.add(containerViewId, fragment, tag);
```

You can then use the `tag` to get a reference to the `Fragment` like this

```
FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

Comment: I am aware of this. That is exactly how I am adding my fragment to the transaction manager (by a TAG). The problem is entirely different, I am unable to retain my savedInstanceState bundle when an orientation change happens because the fragment does not have an ID. I am stumbled as to how to assign an ID to a dynamically created fragment that has been dynamically added to fragmenttransaction object via a TAG.

Comment: Unfortunately I believe the only way to add an ID to a fragment is in xml.