# How do I find the ID of a fragment? Alternatively, how do I give the fragment an ID?

Tags: android, findviewbyid

(First, I'm aware this question has been asked plenty of times, but I haven't found an applicable answer)

I have a fragment created as such:

```
inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_task_ongoing, container, false );
```

What I'd like, is to use findFragmentById in the FragmentActivity, like this:

```
TaskActiveFragment f = ( TaskActiveFragment ) getSupportFragmentManager ().findFragmentById ( R.id.fragment_task_ongoing );
```

Unfortunately, this returns null. The apparent reason is that the id used as a parameter, is the id of the RelativeLayout being inflated, and not the Fragment. First lines of the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_task_ongoing"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp" >
```

So, how do I find out what ID the *fragment* has? If it doesn't have an ID, how do I give it one? Programatically? XML?

Edit: My fragments are added to a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, which is then added to a ViewPager.

Comment: Answer can be found here. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9363072/827110

Comment: I don't see how the answer is applicable. It seems so assume the fragments are added in a different way from mine, using FragmentTransaction.add().

Comment: and how do you add your fragment to the Activity layout ?

Comment: Via a FragmentStatePagerAdapter to a ViewPager.

Comment: The fragment id is not part of the fragment itself. The id you are looking for is the container's id.

Comment: That's what I thought first, but the code (above) returns null. Also an answer in a different thread claimed that wasn't the case. At this point I have no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided you keep a reference to your FragmentStatePagerAdapter and to the index of the Fragment in view, you can call [getItem(int position)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html#getItem%28int%29) on your FragmentStatePagerAdapter, which will return the Fragment.

Comment: This works, and it's a *lot* simpler than some other suggestions I've seen in other threads.