# Where can I find ID of a fragment. And how can I get access to the view of a fragment from MainActivity class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I created a tabbed `Activity` and I have to modify some views from the `MainActivity` class. How can I get access to any of these three fragments created from that Activity?

I know the method involving the use of `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);`, but I don't know where I can find fragment ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Set fragment id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363072/android-set-fragment-id)

Comment: @Sam. It's not the same question at all, in my opinion. Firstly, I asked for "How to find" that ID, but not "How to set" it. Secondly, I search for a method to modify fragment views from activity. For example - setting the text in TextView but from the Activity.

Comment: if you read that question correctly it says _How can I set a Fragment's Id so that I can use getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.--)?_ in order to find you need to set it somewhere.. scroll the answer's its all there

Answer (score 0):

While doing the fragment transaction you might consider setting an id by yourself and later you can retrieve the `Fragment` using that id as well.

Here's how you set up and id/tag for your `Fragment` which is being launched.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, new YourFragment(), "FRAGMENT_1").commit();
```

Now you can retrieve the `Fragment` using the id (i.e. tag) like the following.

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_1");
```

Now to answer your other question, which is how you can access a view component of your `Fragment` from your `Activity` class, you can do this in multiple ways.

One possible option of doing this is having a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Fragment` which can be invoked to update views inside the `Fragment` while the broadcast is received from your `Activity`. Here's a sample `Fragment` with a `BroadcastReceiver` to explain the idea behind.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        // Start listening for the broadcast sent from the Activity
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(mYourBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("MESSAGE_FROM_ACTIVITY"));

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, null, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        // The BroadcastReceiver must be destroyed when your Fragment is being destroyed
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mYourBroadcastReceiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mYourBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // This will be invoked when a broadcast is received from your Activity
            // Update your views here
        }
    };
}
```

Now send the broadcast from your `Activity` like this when needed.

```
Intent intent =new Intent("MESSAGE_FROM_ACTIVITY");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot, but it's too difficult for me to understand 'BroadcastReceiver'. What about setting up a tag for 'Fragment' - I've got error on 2nd argument. "Found: 'com.tesing.fragmentapp.MyFragment', required: 'android.app.Fragment'". My Fragment class extends 'Fragment' and everything seems to be correct.

Comment: Please check if `MyFragment` extends the `support.v4.Fragment`. Look into the imports of your `MyFragment` class. Use the `Fragment` instead of `support.v4.Fragment`.

Comment: This advice causes error, because I created app from a scratch and everywhere is imported only `support.v4.Fragment` and now I'm getting error 
`getItem(int)' in 'com.testing.example.MainActivity.SectionsPagerAdapter' clashes with 'getItem(int)' in 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter'; attempting to use incompatible return type`

Comment: Then you need to use getSupportFragmentManager instead of getFragmetManager

Comment: I tried everything I could try and I get nothing (As I noticed, `findFragmentByTag()` returns `null`). It's a way easier to declare view from `onCreateView()` as `static` and get memory leakage and break Instant Run than make this code work correctly.