# nullpointerexception when calling fragment methods from activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, fragment

i have a fragmentactivity which calls other fragment by :

```
FragmentView1 f = (FragmentView1) this.getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(getFragmentTag(0));
```

and my getFragmentTag() function is :

```
private String getFragmentTag(int pos){
    return "android:switcher:"+R.id.viewpager+":"+pos;   //fragmentpageradapter auto generated tag
}
```

not the problem is whenever i call f.somemethod , i get a nullpointerexception .

i tried with

```
Log.w("HELLO1",""+ f.getTag());
```

it return nullpointerexception .

Comment: My guess is your `getFragmentTag(0)` is not returning what you are expecting

Comment: no , it's returning the correct tag . i called 'getTag()' inside my FragmentView1 , and 'getFragmentTag(0)' in my fragmentActivity , and both returned the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findFragmentByTag() is returning null because it is not finding a fragment with the specified tag as per the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentByTag%28java.lang.String%29).  Ensure you are setting the fragment's tag in your layout or programatically at transaction time.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374170/how-to-set-a-fragment-tag-by-code) question for more information on this.

Comment: i am using fragmentpageradapter , which automatically generates tags for the fragments , for which i am using getFragmentTag , which retrieves that auto generated tag of the fragment