# android - how to set a TAG for a dynamically created fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I set a TAG for fragment that is created like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
    switch (position) {
        case 0: return new scanFragment();
        case 1: return new shopingListFragment();
        case 2: return new PayOnlineFragment();
    }
    return new scanFragment();
}
```

I want to set a TAG to be able to communicate between fragments using interfaces.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374170/how-to-set-a-fragment-tag-by-code

Comment: @mrak I checked this post before I asked, still didn't help. I am not using fargments with xml nor do they have a name so that I can refer to them when using sth like: beginTransaction()

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the `Fragment` class does not expose any setter for the tag. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

However a `Fragment` always has a tag (at least once they are attached, maybe earlier im'm not sure). So you can use `getTag()` to get the tag of your fragment and use it to communicate with it.