# Get fragment from backstack for second time

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

i'm currently working on browser app for an android. I'm managing new tabs with fragments. So everything is working fine when user open new tab B, and then go back again to tab A. The problem appear when from A he try to go back again to B. With other words its not working when you tries to pop back same fragment for the second time.

This is how I'm adding new tabs- fragments

```
    android.app.Fragment f1 = new FragmentHolder();
    allFragments.add(f1);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, f1).addToBackStack(fragmentTags[allFragments.size()-1]).commit();
```

and here how I'm popping back the fragment

```
boolean chkFlag = getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(currentTag.getFragmentTAG(),0);
```

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below function in your Activity,

```
private void loadFragmentAnimated(Fragment fragment, Bundle args, int containerId, String title)
    {
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(containerId, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

Then Added Fragment by using ,

```
loadFragmentAnimated(c, null, R.id.container_name, "title");
```

And remove fragment by using,

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container_name)).commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but how I will keep track of all fragments in backstack without tag?

Comment: you can track fragment by container id

Comment: do refer this  [post] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374170/how-to-set-a-fragment-tag-by-code)

Comment: this is not getting the fragment from backstack, you're just removing and recreating it?!