# How to show fragment on performing certain action

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

Actually I am developing an app which has navigation drawer ,I want to use fragment instead of separate activities . 
I want to how it can be done?
Thanks In advance.

Comment: Add a frame layout to your navigationdrawer activity and make fragments and then use fragment manager to show it ....

Comment: please refer the [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623912/get-fragment-from-backstack-for-second-time/42624124#42624124)

Comment: @SushilDubey actually I created one fragment and it's layout file , I included it in it in my main activity's layout file , and created fragment Manager , fragment transaction begin .. Etc 
But content in fragment is being shown directly irrespective of any action .

Comment: Add the fragment only after you perform your action

Comment: @AyushKhare Yeah I have done the same thing , when user selects one of the options in navigation drawer ,this fragment should be called.

Comment: Then post some code please, and you don't need to include your fragment layout in your activity layout! You need a frame layout and you will place you fragment using fragment transaction

Comment: I suggest you read the tutorial on http://developer.android.com.

Answer (score 0):

Check this sample code.Hope this helps you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout">
        <!--The Toolbar Layout if you have toolbar-->
    </include>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/base_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!--The layout where you need to add different
            fragments on click of nabigation items-->

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <!--The navigation drawer items-->
</LinearLayout>
```